# Issue with Angular from global functions, broken since beta 1.3.0b15. Need help please

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

## Angular JS Controller Issue

---

Sorry for this long post.  I'm sure this is a simple issue and I've just worked all night and gone blind to it, but hopefully someone can help!

---

This is my angular example issue. I am converting XML to Json than parsing it with angular. My controller won't work since it's defined globally.  It stopped working in Angular.JS version 1.3.0 beta 15.  I've tried the stuff I laid out below to fix it but I'm getting no where.

I'm not super experienced in angular but do know many other languages so it's just not making sense to me.  Maybe someone here can help me.  I've done my best to explain it below.

This plunker is an example of it working with it's controller defined as a global function in angular 1.0.4.  I have also put a readme.md explaining the issues in detail!

http://plnkr.co/edit/fLgVHV1gJSigIB6jfZDH

---

The issue is obviously known and outlined on github at the angular.js log.

### [feat($controller): disable using global controller constructors](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018)

With the exception of simple demos, it is not helpful to use globals
for controller constructors. This adds a new method to `$controllerProvider`
to re-enable the old behavior, but disables this feature by default.

BREAKING CHANGE:
`$controller` will no longer look for controllers on `window`.
The old behavior of looking on `window` for controllers was originally intended
for use in examples, demos, and toy apps. We found that allowing global controller
functions encouraged poor practices, so we resolved to disable this behavior by
default.

To migrate, register your controllers with modules rather than exposing them
as globals:

Before:

```js
function MyController() {
...
}
```

After:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyController', [function() {
// ...
}]);
```

[You can see the notes about the breaking change located here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018)

---

[FURTHER EXPLAINED BY ANGULAR.JS HERE](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d5305d565285ed805278ad7ad71b3b34b3e761c6)

The following example is given at that previous link:

```js
<example>
    <example module="selectExample">
      <file name="index.html">
         <script>
        function MyCntrl($scope) {
          $scope.colors = [
            {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
            {name:'white', shade:'light'},
            {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
            {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
             {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
          ];
          $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red
        }
        angular.module('selectExample', [])
          .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.colors = [
              {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
              {name:'white', shade:'light'},
              {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
              {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
              {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
            ];
            $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red
          }]);
       </script>
        <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
           <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="color in colors">
               Name: <input ng-model="color.name">
```

---

## [I tried to redefine it as a angular function at this plunker][3]

So based off the example I would think that i need to change my code from:

```js
var AppController = function($scope, DataSource) {
    var SOURCE_FILE = "example.xml";
    xmlTransform = function(data) {
        console.log("transform data");
        var x2js = new X2JS();
        var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
        return json.xmldata.Categories;
    };
    setData = function(data) {
        $scope.dataSet = data;
    };
    DataSource.get(SOURCE_FILE, setData, xmlTransform);
};
```

and change it to this:

```js
    myApp.controller('AppController', function($scope, Datasource) {
      var SOURCE_FILE = "example.xml";
      xmlTransform = function(data) {
          console.log("transform data");
          var x2js = new X2JS();
          var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
          return json.xmldata.Categories;
      };
      setData = function(data) {
          $scope.dataSet = data;
      };
      DataSource.get(SOURCE_FILE, setData, xmlTransform);
  });
```

[When i do that, I get this error:](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=DatasourceProvider%20%3C-%20Datasource%20%3C-%20AppController)

> Error: $injector:unpr
>
> Unknown Provider
>
> Unknown provider: DatasourceProvider <- Datasource <- AppController
>
> Description

---

#### [A work around that is VERY UNWANTED! but works...](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9tMKJS2SB62zxG8PueN)

One thing to note that as quoted from the angular.js github:

Although it's not recommended, you can re-enable the old behavior like this:

```js
angular.module('myModule').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  // this option might be handy for migrating old apps, but please don't use it
  // in new ones!
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

However, I'd prefer not to have this global function out there.  I'm not sure if the issue is something to do with the XML2JSON script i'm using or what.  I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject the DateSource `factory` object like this:

```
myApp.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'DataSource', function($scope, DataSource) {
     ...
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help i'll try it and let you know how it works.

Comment: I am getting the same Uncaught Error [$injector:modulerr]
Also This is giving me a syntax error, Unexpected String.

Comment: Please see my modified answer.

Comment: It makes sense now.  Thanks man! http://plnkr.co/edit/5A2NQJIYP4lXJd2Hi2kD

I also had to do var myApp = ....

Thanks alot for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

change it to

```
myApp.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$Datasource', AppController]);
```

basically the second parameter should be an array, whose last argument should be a function which provider the controller definition.

**EDIT**

to fix the myApp issue use below syntax

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$Datasource', AppController]);
```

or

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['myApp.service']);
```

you are using myApp variable without defining it (either store the module in a variable called myApp or get the module on runtime to define the controller)

Comment: Thank you alot for your help. I'll try it out.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NRacO8TFeCCRHQE40xa3?

I had tried this once before and a couple variations and i keep getting the same error... 

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp

Comment: Hey I appreciate it.  The solution is here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5A2NQJIYP4lXJd2Hi2kD

I needed do do var myApp = ...

I have a service also.

I really appreciate your assistance!

Comment: I believe this answer would work as well though.  

Thanks again for the help.  I had been banging my head on the wall!